# SQLITE DataBase Android function not working

Tags: android

I have this DataBase wich I implementeded for keep some data in it. I have no error but my insertData function is not working with 2 parameters!!

```
public class PersonDataBaseHelper {

private static final String TAG = PersonDataBaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();

// database configuration
// if you want the onUpgrade to run then change the database_version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";

// table configuration
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "person_table";         // Table name
private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
     // a column named "_id" is required for cursor

private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME = "person_name";
private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_USERNAME = "person_username";

private DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

// this is a wrapper class. that means, from outside world, anyone will communicate with PersonDatabaseHelper,
// but under the hood actually DatabaseOpenHelper class will perform database CRUD operations
public PersonDataBaseHelper(Context aContext) {

    openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(aContext);
    database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    database = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
}

public Cursor getAllData () {

    String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    Log.d(TAG, "getAllData SQL: " + buildSQL);

    return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
}
public void insertData (String aPersonName,String username) {

    // we are using ContentValues to avoid sql format errors

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, aPersonName);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_USERNAME, username);

    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}

public Cursor getSomeData(String text){



    return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID,PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME},
            PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE ?", new String[] {"%" + text + "%"},
            null, null, null);

}


public boolean deleteSingleRow(long rowId)
{

    return database.delete(TABLE_NAME, PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
// this DatabaseOpenHelper class will actually be used to perform database related operation

private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context aContext) {
        super(aContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        // Create your tables here

        String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME+" TEXT,"+PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_USERNAME+" TEXT )";

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate SQL: " + buildSQL);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Database schema upgrade code goes here

        String buildSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

        Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade SQL: " + buildSQL);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);       // drop previous table

        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);               // create the table from the beginning
    }
}
```

My insertData function is not working , because of my second parameter. If I comment this line :
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_USERNAME, username)

My insertData function will word just fine... I can't find the problem in my dataBase. All others function works from my database. I am kind of newbie in android programming.. Sorry if I didn't write a quite good english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way, it's better

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLA_NAME+" ('"+aPersonNameCOLUMN+"','"+usernameCOLUMN+"') VALUES ('"+aPersonName+"','"+username+"') ");
```

replace the aPersonNameCOLUMN and the usernameCOLUMN with your own columns

Answer (score 0):

In this code everything looks ok. Why do you know that this function is not working if you've got no error? Are you sure that String username which you want to put in database is not null or just equals("")? Please show your code from place where you try to use that function.

Comment: I know is not working , because is not inserting my data in my database

Answer (score 0):

```
 String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME+" TEXT,"+PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_USERNAME+" TEXT )";
```